# What does the nullity of T have to do with if it's isomorphic or not?

Tags: linear-algebra

The nullity, or dimension of the kernel of T, seems to have some sort of relation with isomorphism or at least injectivity.

For example, my notes say: `dim KerT = 1 > 0 so not injective and not isomorphic.`

What is this relationship specifically?

Comment: What does injectivity imply about the kernel?

Comment: Good question. I'm not sure.

Comment: An isomorphism must be injective.

Comment: Recapitulate the definitions. What does it mean for $T$ to be injective, what is $\ker T$? Ponder the relation.

Comment: Injective means one-to-one and kernel is what you multiply T by to get 0 vector.

Comment: The fact that you have a nontrivial kernel means that there is a $v\neq 0$ such that $Tv=0$. What else maps to zero?

Comment: In the usual math terminology, "$T$ is isomorphic" is **not** another way of saying "$T$ is an isomorphism".

Comment: @Omnomnomnom what's the difference?

Comment: The word isomorphic is used to describe spaces, not maps.  We say that $V$ and $W$ are *isomorphic* if and only if there is an *isomorphism* between them.  When you say something like "$T$ *is isomorphic*", a mathematician's instinct is to ask "isomorphic to what"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A linear map $T$ is *an isomorphism* if and only if it both injective (one-to-one) and surjective (onto).

A linear map $T$ is injective if and only if $\dim(\ker(T)) = 0$.  Try to show that this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

The underlying theorem is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem

In your special case, if $\dim(\mathrm{Ker} T)>0$ you know that there is $v\neq 0$ such that $Tv=0$. So $Tv=T0$ and the map is not injective.